# PowerPoint opens old version of file instead of the most recently saved

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, sharepoint

I have a presentation I have worked on for some hours, and which I have saved regularly.

When going to the open file dialogue in PowerPoint I see that it is last saved ~5 minutes ago.

[image]

However, when opening the file, I get a version of it which was last saved 4 hours ago, without any of the changes made since then.

[image]

I assume there is some issue with syncing between my (temporary?) local copy of the file and the SharePoint version, but is there any way I can figure out which is which, and not least get the most recently saved file, no matter where it is stored?

Comment: This is what the "office upload center" is all about - to create an impression of saving the file to the server without really trying. The most recent version is _probably_ in the "upload queue", accessible from the system tray. On the other hand, I don't know an universal method of disabling this "feature", so I am leaving only a comment.

Comment: @fraxinus I believe the upload center was removed from our computers through an office update a few months back, but I'll double-check if it was really removed when I turn on my work computer again